# Cómo clono una carpeta específica en Git?

Tags: git

Holas!
Quiero clonar la carpeta **react** de este repositorio:
https://github.com/surveyjs/code-examples/tree/main/get-started-creator
He intentado con:

```
git clone https://github.com/surveyjs/code-examples main/get-started-creator/react
```

Y otras formas más con *--single-branch*, pero no logro.

Alguien me ayuda por favor?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Creo que lo que buscas es un [sparse checkout](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-sparse-checkout), una funcionalidad disponible en Git 2.25.0 que te permitiría mantener localmente el repositorio pero descargar solo aquella carpeta que te interesa.

```
git clone --depth 1 --filter=blob:none --sparse https://github.com/surveyjs/code-examples.git
cd code-examples
git sparse-checkout set get-started-creator/react/
```

Fuente: [How do I clone a subdirectory only of a Git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/600079/how-do-i-clone-a-subdirectory-only-of-a-git-repository)